# .Include Forces EF to throw sequence contains no elements

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

existing SQL Server Tables

Two Tests :

Call this one A:

```
    [Test]
    public void AssertAccessPolicyWithIdAndChecksum()
    {
        var pol = Repo.GetPolicyFlightStatus(aut_id: 44544, checksum: "QXSDENY");
        Assert.NotNull(pol);
    }
```

call this one B

```
    [Test]
    public void AssertGetFriendlyPolicy()
    {
        var lineRepo = new tbl_StatusRepository();
        var pol = Repo.GetPolicyFlightStatus(aut_id: 44544, checksum: "QXSDENY");
        Assert.AreEqual("With Underwriter", pol.tbl_Status.txt_friendlyName);
        Assert.AreEqual("WC/Longshore", pol.tbl_Line.txt_friendlyName);
    }
```

Models :

```
public partial class tbl_Policy
{
    [Key]
    public int aut_id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("tbl_Status")]
    public int int_statusID { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Status tbl_Status { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("tbl_Line")]
    public int int_lineID { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Line tbl_Line { get; set; }
}

public class tbl_Status
{
    [Key]
    public int aut_id { get; set; }
    public string txt_status { get; set; }
    public string txt_friendlyName { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Policy tbl_Policy { get; set; }
}

public class tbl_Line
{
    [Key]
    public int aut_id { get; set; }
    public string txt_Line { get; set; }
    public string txt_friendlyName { get; set; }
    public virtual tbl_Policy tbl_Policy { get; set; }
}
```

When Running

```
      internal static tbl_Policy GetPolicyFlightStatus(int aut_id, string checksum)
    {
        if (Transcoder.Transcode(aut_id) == checksum)
        {
            var ctx = new LIGDataContext();
            return ctx.tbl_Policy.Include("tbl_Line").Include("tbl_Status").Single(f => f.aut_id == aut_id);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

TestA passes
TestB throws Exception on first Assert Line



Adding Includes For SubTables

```
 internal static tbl_Policy GetPolicyFlightStatus(int aut_id, string checksum)
    {
        if (Transcoder.Transcode(aut_id) == checksum)
        {
            var ctx = new LIGDataContext();
            return ctx.tbl_Policy.Include("tbl_Line").Include("tbl_Status").Single(f => f.aut_id == aut_id);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Test A and Test B  Throw 
LIG2010RedesignMVC3.LIGMVC2010FlightTrackerTests.AssertAccessPolicyWithIdAndChecksum:
System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements

---

LIG2010RedesignMVC3.LIGMVC2010FlightTrackerTests.AssertGetFriendlyPolicy:
System.InvalidOperationException : Sequence contains no elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems in your object model. Basically, you are trying to set up a 1:1 association with foreign keys while code first does not really support this scenario. As a result it turns all of your associations to Shared Primary Key Associations and none of the foreign keys on tbl_Policy become a foreign key in the database. First, you need to fix your model since that could cause a bunch of exceptions at runtime.

Currently, there ar two ways to map a 1:1 association in Code-First:

[**1. Shared Primary Key Associations**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/19/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-one-to-one-shared-primary-key-associations.aspx)

[**2. One-to-One Foreign Key Associations**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/23/associations-in-ef-code-first-ctp5-part-3-one-to-one-foreign-key-associations.aspx)

See which one better describes your domain model and I can change your object model to match that.

Comment: I was trying to do one-to-Many So thats some help now I just have to figure out why my mapping is still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to rework my modeling  (credit to Morteza but I wanted it here for my records

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<tbl_Line>()
            .HasMany(d => d.tbl_Policy)
            .WithRequired(c => c.tbl_Line)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.int_lineID);
        modelBuilder.Entity<tbl_Status>()
            .HasMany(d => d.tbl_Policy)
            .WithRequired(c => c.tbl_Status)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.int_statusID);
    }
```

Comment: Glad you figure this one out. Let me know if you have any questions on this.